# What rule (Resharper/C# .editorconfig) rewrites "throw new()" as "throw new Exception()"?

Tags: c#, resharper, editorconfig

I'm running the Resharper CLI on check-in to clean up C# code Prettier-style.  It works great but I'm running into an issue where `throw new()` is rewritten as `throw new Exception()`.  We use this mainly as a very brief sanity check for nullables, e.g. `return somethingNullable ?? throw new()`

The only rule I found in .editorconfig for exception/new/throw was:

`csharp_style_throw_expression = true:suggestion`

But deleting this rule does not fix the issue.

I tried a `--verbose` log, and while it shows all file output, it doesn't seem to provide a clue about what rule is actually causing the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's `csharp_object_creation_when_type_not_evident` (see [R# docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/EditorConfig_CSHARP_CSharpCodeStylePageImplSchema.html#resharper_csharp_object_creation_when_type_not_evident)).